# Computing $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+7}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the primitive function of $$\frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+7}}$$

[Attempt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dh1nvcs7aj4gdt/2013-10-29%2013.15.16.jpg). And my answer is 
$$\arcsin \left( \frac{\sqrt{\left( x^{2}+7 \right)}}{\sqrt{7}} \right)$$

Why am I wrong? See link for whole calculation.

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1/(x%5E2sqrt(x%5E2+7)).

Comment: The title reminds me of an anecdote. Q: what is $\int 1$? A: $\int 1 = \int \frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{1}{d}\ln |x| + C$.

Comment: There is a typo in what you gave to Alpha.

Comment: @jacob: you typed it wrong on WA, see: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%5E2+sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+7%29%29

Comment: @Amzoti is $$-x/(2 sqrt(7) (x^2)^(3/2)) = \arcsin \left( \frac{\sqrt{\left( x^{2}+7 \right)}}{\sqrt{7}} \right)$$ ?

Comment: If you take the [*derivative*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+-sqrt%28x%5E2%2B7%29%2F%287+x%29%2Bconstant), what do you get? Now take the derivative of your result. You should always get back the integrand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $x=1/u$; $dx=-du/u^2$.  Then sub $v=u^2$.  The result is a fairly simple integral.

**EDIT**

$$\begin{align}\underbrace{\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+7}}}_{u=1/x} &= -\int \frac{du}{u^2} \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1/u^2+7}} \\ &= -\underbrace{\int du \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+7 u^2}}}_{v=u^2} \\ &= -\frac12 \underbrace{\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+7 v}}}_{y=7 v}\\ &= -\frac{1}{14} \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y}}\\ &= -\frac17 \sqrt{1+y}+C\\&= -\frac{\sqrt{x^2+7}}{7 x}+C\end{align}$$

Comment: no, it's not simple. please show me the solution.

Comment: the second sub, $v=u^2$ leads to nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let, $x^2+7=t^2x^2\implies 2xdx=2xt^2dx+2tx^2dt\implies dx=\frac {xt dt}{1-t^2}$

Given integral, $I=\int\frac { \frac {xt dt}{1-t^2}}{\frac {7}{t^2-1}.xt}=-\int\frac {dt}{7}=- \frac t7+c=\sqrt {1+\frac {7}{x^2}}+c$

And Jacob obviously you are wrong since $\frac {\sqrt {x^2+7}}{\sqrt 7}=\sqrt {1+\frac{x^2}{7}}\geq 1$ So $\arcsin \frac {\sqrt {x^2+7}}{\sqrt 7}$ seems to be undefined !!